# Internet Explorer hides php content

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

The problem is i'm not so advanced so i definitely did something wrong..

First page on he site opens correctly on Chrome and Firefox,
but on Internet Explorer footer image sticks to header image hiding two images in between.

the website: http://www.joniart.com

I've tried to make a similar landing html page, with `<div>` content but the issue remains.

Comment: what do you mean by php content

Comment: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fjoniart.com%2Fnews%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0 shows 15 errors and 1 warning. Fix the errors, then see if it works.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid and therefore might render differently in different browsers.  Try using http://validator.w3.org/ to find and fix the invalid markup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the height of those elements:

```
<img width="355" height="inherit" alt="Lietuviskai" src="http://joniart.com/wp-content/themes/tut/static_images/ranka_k.jpg" border="0" complete="complete"/>
```

Give them a real height

```
<img width="355" height="300" alt="Lietuviskai" src="http://joniart.com/wp-content/themes/tut/static_images/ranka_k.jpg" border="0" complete="complete"/>
```

and they should work.

From MDN:

> **height**
>
> The height of the image in HTML5 CSS pixels, or HTML 4 in
>   pixels or as a percentage.

I don't thinkg `inherit` is a valid value.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Img

Comment: You've got width twice now...

Comment: Yeah just noticed. Fixed.

Comment: Thank you a lot!
i said it has to be incredibly stupid ;))